# Why is 每天到深夜都忙 wrong?

Tags: grammar, complement

This is a faulty sentence from the HSK6 Standard Course (page 71; [photo of original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zlicE.jpg)):

> 她不是看书就是写文章，每天到深夜都忙。

The corrected version is the following (and there's no further explanation):

> 她不是看书就是写文章，每天**都忙到深夜**。  [补语位置不当]

I'm perfectly happy to accept the corrected sentence as correct; we often say things like 睡到9点 and 工作到深夜 and 加班到7点, and the given sentence is a correct use of the complement.  But I don't understand why the first sentence is incorrect.

With a bit of Googling, this seems to be a generalizable error (and therefore worth knowing):

> 到7点加班 (✗)  加班到7点  (✓)
> 到7点学习 (✗)  学习到7点  (✓)
> 到7点工作 (✗)  工作到7点  (✓)
> 到7点睡觉 (✗)  睡到7点  (✓)

The impression I'm getting is that if we say `到 + [time] + [verb]`, then `[verb]` takes place *at* and/or *after* `[time]` (as opposed to `[verb]` taking place *up until* `[time]`, as the speaker intended).  So we can say 到深夜才回家 or 到深夜就下班.

Still, there seems to be sentences like these:

> 他从下午四点，干到凌晨3点多，每天到深夜工作11个小时。  ([source](http://news.china.com.cn/live/2018-09/02/content_169445.htm))
> ……，每天到深夜都有顾客，…… ([source](https://www.ts.cn/xwzx/dzxw/201904/t20190419_6226188.shtml))
> 从早上一直到晚上12点都忙碌不停 ([source](https://wen.baidu.com/question/1615360722014056187.html))

It'd be nice to identify the definitive reason the given sentence wrong, so I don't make the same mistake (not just here, but in general).

**Question**: Why is 每天到深夜都忙 wrong?

Answer (score 2):

到(time)都(predicate) can only be used when the predicate describes a state, not an action. Compare:

他每天都学习到深夜 (correct)

他每天到深夜都学习 (incorrect)

他每天到深夜都在学习 (correct)

他每天都在学习到深夜 (incorrect)

Another group:

每天到深夜都有顾客 (correct)

每天都有顾客到深夜 (incorrect)

每天都有顾客待到深夜 (correct)

每天到深夜都有顾客待 (incorrect, mainly because 待 is missing its own complement)

> 每天到深夜工作11个小时

This reads not very natural to me. I would write 每天工作11个小时直到深夜

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is with the word 忙. It is not customary to use 忙 alone as a verb. If you replace 忙 with 哭 and write "(她)每天到深夜都哭(v)", then the sentence would be correct. Using 忙 in 每天到深夜都忙 as a verb would require 在 before 忙, e.g. "(她)每天到深夜都在忙"

每天都**忙到**深夜 is a way to fix the problem of 忙 alone as a verb

每天到深夜都**忙於**工作 is another way

Answer (score 0):

Just to say, correct or wrong, without attempting to say why is not helpful.

If you just look at:

(她)每天到深夜都忙.

and you wish to look at language in Greek Propositional Logic terms, with a Subject and a Predicate, which is where the Western Grammar notions come from, there are 3 candidates for the Subject: 她, 天 and 夜.

The Predicate is everything which is not the Subject.
每天, every day, and 到深夜, till late, indicate times and do not describe an object directly.
忙, busy is a 形容词, but can't really describe 天 or 夜.
她 is who we are talking about here and 她 can be described as 忙. Assume she is the Subject.

```
1. 她忙.
2. 她忙吗?
3. 她每天都忙.
```

Now, you want to qualify 忙, say something about 忙.

```
1. 她每天都忙到深夜.  
   She is busy every day till late.
```

Tang Ho introduced a prepositional phrase:

她每天到深夜都忙於工作.
She is busy with work till late every day.

Now we have 忙於工作, busy with work. 於工作

```
1. 她工作.
2. 她忙于工作.
3. 她每天都忙于工作.
4. 她每天都忙于到深夜工作.
5. 她每天都忙到深夜于工作.
6. 她每天到深夜都忙于工作
```

Now which number sentences, from 1 to 6 above do you like, and why?